# Laravel giving 500 internal error on centos 7 with apache and php 7

Tags: apache, centos7, php-7, laravel-5.4

I am new to centos. I have installed apache and php 7. I have also installed all php extensions required for laravel.

I have an laravel app working fine on windows.I have just transferred my code from windows to centos 7.The problem is now it shows 500 internal error in console on every route.
I have changed .htaccess code as explained here:

**https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls**

folder rights to storage and bootstrap is set to 777, also enabled mod_rewrite.

Also when I installed fresh laravel its not working. When i am updating the main route in web.php from

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

to

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'welcome';
});
```

It shows welcome message but for

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

getting 500 internal error in console and blank page appears.

[httpd Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfGex.png)

Comment: Please check your log files and show us the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor i am using laravel 5.4. Same issue i am facing when using nginx instead of apache.

Comment: Well thats wierd, i run it without trubbel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
You have to enable .htaccess by adding this to your vhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/yourfoldername/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Step 2: And  disabled SELinux permanently.
[Click here](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/)

Answer (score 0):

As your error log file shows , there are a permission issue in writing log files .

you may try :-

1- disable logging , or in other words disable `Monolog` package "**Unrecommended**"

2- tracking your error logs shows as said that there are a permission issue in writing logs , as you said :-

> folder rights to storage and bootstrap is set to 777

so please make sure that you've changed the `storage` directory permission to 777 **recursively**