# Laravel returning server error 500 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, server, centos, vps

As the title says, I have a VPS running on CentOS 7, I installed all the requisites for Laravel, PHP 7.3, but it still giving me 'Server Error 500'.

Note that this is a fresh installation of Laravel with composer.

- My CentOS version is *CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)*
- PHP version is *PHP 7.3.6 (cli)*
- I manually installed all the necessary modules from PHP

### What I have already tried

I already did quite a lot of research:
[Laravel giving 500 internal error on centos 7 with apache and php 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385659/laravel-giving-500-internal-error-on-centos-7-with-apache-and-php-7) 
I followed what the answer to that questions says and still the same for me.
I did also set up permissions correctly following this other post:
[How to set up File Permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
Also these ones 
[Getting a 500 Internal Server Error on Laravel 5+ Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/apache/how-to-fix-http-error-code-500-internal-server-error/

And a bunch of more articles I read on another websites.

These are the permissions for the project folder:
`drwxr-xr-x 13 apache apache 4096 May 31 05:23 laravel`

And for storage:
`drwxr-xr-x  5 apache apache   4096 May 31 04:44 storage`

Tried generating the key and got this:

```
[root@server laravel]# php artisan key:generate

   ErrorException  : file_get_contents(/var/www/laravel/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92|     {
     93|         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94|             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95|             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  >  96|             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97|         ));
     98|     }
     99|
    100|     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   file_get_contents("/var/www/laravel/.env")
      /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand::writeNewEnvironmentFileWith("base64:soTdeaCmsY1ELnpJLCcYkBJjY6SWiLYwY+Mvoxl9wOw=")
      /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:80

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
[root@server laravel]#
```

Comment: Could post as well the permissions you gave to the storage folder and the owner/group of your project folder on the server?

Comment: Also make sure your .env file contains an application key. If that's not the case you can generate a new one by typing: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @mdexp I added the permissions to the question. I'll try that, thanks

Comment: @mdexp I got an error running that command, it says it cannot open .env, added that also

Comment: Then you miss the Laravel environment configuration file. You should have a .env.example file on the fresh Laravel installation. Duplicate that one and rename it to .env then run the key:generate command

Comment: Indeed, I didn't have a .env file. That fixed my issue, add that as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you miss the Laravel environment configuration file.

In a fresh Laravel installation you should have a .env.example file. Duplicate that one and rename it to .env then run the `php artisan key:generate` command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the `var/www/laravel/.env` file from your `var/www/laravel/.env.example` file?

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it configuring properly the `.env` and generating a key as @mdexp mentioned.
So for everyone having problems, check the links in my question and set everything correctly